# Filters - Hilbert Transform and Absolute Value of Magnitude Response

Tags: filters, dsp-core, hilbert-transform

Following relationship between magnitude response and phase response for minimum phase:

[image]

I have implemented in C++ code using the Hilbert Transform C code from file found online [ht.c](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/apdet/apdet-1.0/ht.c). However, I am not getting the phase response as expected. My magnitude response follows raised cosine formula:

[image]
Essentially I provide $|H(j\omega)| = \text{Gain}(f)$ to be all real values as per this cosine formula. The phase response is not as expected. Also, how am I suppose to handle $\log(|H(i\omega)|)$ when $|H(i\omega)| = 0$? Am I missing any steps to obtain phase response in this process?

Here is how phase and magnitude response should look like:

[image]

Comment: What did you expect the phase to look like? Also note that there is no problem with zero values because (at least from the figure) the magnitude never becomes zero. Furthermore, the phase is not defined when the magnitude is zero, so this is not a relevant problem. (What phase does the value $0$ have?) But now comes the most important question: what are you going to do with the phase response if you manage to compute it from the given magnitude response? In what way are you expecting it to help you when designing the filter?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after but I think you might be on the wrong track.

Comment: Can your code demonstrate the Hilbert transform of $\cos$ is $\sin$? That's the first step. Then test your code satisfies $\left<x,Hx\right> = 0$ and $\left<Hx,Hx\right> = \left<x,x\right>$.

Comment: @MattL. In the definition of filters magnitude response it specifies Gain(f) = 0 (otherwise). Correct me if I am wrong but magnitude is zero there. As for the phase, it should look like as in [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24245/raised-cosine-filter-calculating-phase-response) but I am getting different kind of curve. My filter needs to have this kind minimum phase response, that's the design objective.

Comment: Judging from the figure, the gain is in dB, so it's zero dB, not zero (which would be $-\infty$ dB). Furthermore, the phase in the figure of the other question was most probably just computed from the actual filter, not theoretically via the Hilbert transform.

Comment: Even if you managed to compute the phase via the Hilbert transform, this would probably not at all help you in *designing* the desired filter.

Comment: @MattL.You wrote "most probably just computed from the actual filter". How they can compute phase other than from Hilbert transform if magnitude is given?

Comment: From the actually implemented filter. I guess they designed the filter,  i.e. they somehow approximated that raised cosine shape, and then they just computed the frequency response of the designed filter.

Comment: I have confirmed that Hilbert transform of cos is sin. But when I introduce log(Magnitude) the phase is not as expected.

Comment: you have real problems with your definition.  in your figure the raised cosine is drawn on a log-frequency scale, not a linear-frequency scale. there is symmetry in **log**-frequency, not linear-frequency. so your mathematical definition is inconsistent with that.  (your $W$ and $f$ terms do not have the same dimensions.  you'll likely have to replace $f$ with $\log_2(f)$ somehow, somewhere.)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I have added the magnitude and phase response plot to my question. Frequency f seems to have the same dimension as W - octave relative to 1 kHz. I am still getting a different curve for phase.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I managed to obtain similar phase response - did not take log(|H(w)|), I guess because it is log scale already, it worked. But the phase angle is way bigger than expected. Instead of max 23 deg I have max 196 degrees.

Comment: okay, i don't think you caught the meaning of what i was saying. take a look at your changed question.  -  oh, i can't do it because your math is really a picture.  you should use the $\LaTeX$ feature of this SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neb, i dunno where you got that frequency response expression from, but it's flawed.  from the description (of parameters like $W$ in "octaves"), it should be like this:

$$ Gain(f) = \begin{cases}
10^{Boost/20} \times \frac{1}{2}\left\{1 + \cos\left(\pi \frac{\log_2(f/F_c)}{W} \right) \right\}, & \text{if }|\log_2(f/F_c)|<W \\
0, & \text{otherwise } \end{cases} $$

Comment: I got the formula from [this paper](http://www.twaudio.de/twuploads/Raised%20Cosine%20Equalization%20-%20McGrath%20et%20al_1322147059.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Robert. I assume unit for f and Fc is Hz and for W is octave. I plotted Gain(f) but did not get raised cosine curve (I got several segments instead of one smooth raised cosine). For Hilbert transform I use C code from [here](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/apdet/apdet-1.0/ht.c) It did not give me the phase as in picture. I got correct phase using the formula from paper and plotting xh[i] from "ht.c"  as phase response. Input to paper's formula was f in octave. I didn't use log(Magnitude) but just magnitude when calculating Hilbert transform..